# Git cherry-pick failed to pick the right changes

Tags: git, cherry-pick

**Note**: It was a mistake from my side. I cherry-picked the parent hash. Please see the `update` section.
Original Question:
I have a file `vmu_hw_test` in a branch "test_imu" which has a change similar to seen below

```
if( g_imu_spi.readFromFifo() == 0)
{
    //Find local maxima and minima event
    g_imu_spi.compute_event();
    //compute the euler
    g_imu_spi.compute_euler();
    //From the average values compute the max
    //g_imu_spi.compute_Max();
    g_imu_spi.compute_Max(buffer);
}
```

The `if` statement and the removal of comment were introduced on this commit.
 
And `master` branch had

```
//Find local maxima and minima event
g_imu_spi.compute_event();
//compute the euler
g_imu_spi.compute_euler();
//From the average values compute the max
g_imu_spi.compute_Max(buffer);
```

**Question**
1. As I've read `cherry-pick` takes a single commit change and applies it. Is there a problem if the branches are different (in commit history) 
2. A Microsoft [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180312-00/?p=98215) says not to cherry pick. Is it a bad practice to cherry pick?
3. Why would have cherry pick failed? (**Update**: It did not.)

**Git Diff**
For the latest commit on `test_imu.c`

```
diff --git a/Src/vmu_hw_test.c b/Src/vmu_hw_test.c
index 14b0a67..1954d64 100644
--- a/Src/vmu_hw_test.c
+++ b/Src/vmu_hw_test.c
@@ -2694,14 +2694,16 @@ unsigned short  IMU_sendData(void)
                }
            }
    //Regular run
-                               g_imu_spi.readFromFifo();
-                               //Find local maxima and minima event
-                               g_imu_spi.compute_event();
-                               //compute the euler
-                               g_imu_spi.compute_euler();
-                               //From the average values compute the max
-//                             g_imu_spi.compute_Max();
-                               g_imu_spi.compute_Max(buffer);
+                               if( g_imu_spi.readFromFifo() == 0)
+                               {
+                                   //Find local maxima and minima event
+                                   g_imu_spi.compute_event();
+                                   //compute the euler
+                                   g_imu_spi.compute_euler();
+                                   //From the average values compute the max
+                                   g_imu_spi.compute_Max(buffer);
+                               }
+
```

**Update**
Git cherry-pick did not fail. I tried looking into the diffs as suggested by `torek` and found that the diffs do state that a cherry pick should have included the `if` statement. 
Here's the `git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-C>` (please refer to torek's answer)

```
unsigned short  IMU_sendData(void)    
{
@@ -2703,7 +2731,6 @@ unsigned short  IMU_sendData(void)
                                //compute the euler
                                g_imu_spi.compute_euler();
                                //From the average values compute the max
-//                             g_imu_spi.compute_Max();
                                g_imu_spi.compute_Max(buffer);

                    //Low pass filter for each axis
@@ -2741,28 +2768,8 @@ unsigned short  IMU_sendData(void)
        }
    }
```

And the `git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-A>` is already provided in the `Git Diff` section. From this we can see that the `if` statement should be cherry picked.

What went wrong was that I cherry picked the wrong hash (I picked the parent hash).

Comment: Well, interactive rebase is basically cherry picking with a nicer interface

Comment: Cherry pick applies the *changes* introduced by the commit(s) you cherry pick, not the final state. Could it be that the if-statement wasn't introduced in the commit(s) you chose?

Comment: It was introduced in the commit I cherry picked.

Comment: Can you add the appropriate commit diff output by `git show <commit-id>` (where `<commit-id>` is the commit you're cherry picking?)

Comment: @Timshel Added a git diff. Also is it bad to share my SHA hash publicly?

Comment: The hash itself is only of use to someone who has a copy of your repository, including that particular commit. If the repository is public, it's useful; if not, it's not.

Comment: Instead of showing partial, conflicting, and edited evidence, could you perhaps show the actual evidence you're looking at?   Your presentation here makes the situation much more confusing than the one you're actually looking at yourself.

Comment: @jthill I have a feeling I messed up and took the parent commit's hash as `git cherry-pick <parent SHA>`. And posted the `git diff` of the latest commit. Because when I tried `cherry picking` now, I get the `if statement` after the merge. I can close this question as it's misleading.

Comment: Correcting the evidence would preserve a good answer as torek guessed what was really going on, but it'd be more work for you. I'd like to see it fixed or closed, either would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` works by merging—but the *inputs* to the merge are a bit unusual.

Specifically, with a normal, typical merge, we start with the *commit graph*, from which we find what you have done on your branch, vs what someone else has done on their branch:

```
             A--B--C   <-- you (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             D--E--F   <-- them
```

Each round node, or `*`, or uppercase letter, represents a commit (the actual commits have commit hash IDs, which are are too unwieldy for ordinary humans to work with).  Here, commit `*` is the common starting point, so for Git to combine *your* changes on your branch, Git must compare commit `C`—your latest work—to commit `*`, to see what you changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-C>   # what you changed
```

Likewise, Git must compare commit `F`—their latest work—to commit `*`, to see what they changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-F>   # what they changed
```

Git can now *combine* the two sets of changes.  If you modified line 12 of some file, but they did not, Git takes your change.  If they modified line 20 of that same file, but you did not, Git takes their change.  Both changes get applied to that one file as it appears in commit `*`, to make the merged version of that file.

(For a real merge, eventually, Git makes a *merge commit*, which remembers both branch tips, but for cherry-pick that does not happen.)

Cherry-pick uses this same merge machinery to accomplish a cherry-pick, but this time, the *merge base* is not some common starting commit.  Instead, it's the *parent* of the commit whose name or hash ID you give to `git cherry-pick`:

```
...--o--o--o--o--A   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       o--o--B--C   <-- test_imu
```

If you are in this situation, with commit `A` being your current commit because you are on `master`, and you issue the command:

```
git cherry-pick test_imu
```

Git makes a *merge* with the merge base being commit `B`—the parent of commit `C`, which is the commit you are picking—and commits `C` and `A` being the two commits that get compared:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-A>   # what you did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-C>   # what they did
```

Git now combines these changes.  You get a merge conflict where you both made differing changes, but to the same line(s) of the same file.

If the `if` test is *removed* by going from commit `B` to commit `A`, but nothing in `B`-to-`C` touches the `if` test, Git assumes that the correct action is to *keep the removal* of the `if` test.  The only way to know for sure *why* Git did what Git did, though, is to look at the three inputs, e.g., by running those two `git diff` commands.

I find it quite helpful to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, so that when there *is* a conflict, Git includes the base-commit file section, as well as the two conflicting changes.  This often makes it unnecessary to look at commit `B` directly.  In particularly complex cases, though, you may want to look at all three inputs.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! Is it possible to raise an `issue` on git to include a feature like what I expected it to be? I couldn't find a `issues` tab for github git repo

Comment: Also, how to see the git diff file-rename of a specific file? <commit id>/Src/file doesn't work

Comment: The GitHub copy of Git is just a mirror; Git has its own mailing list, with its own protocol. If there's a rename that `--find-renames` finds, it's a bit tricky to diff just the one file (Git has to compare the entire tree to *find* the rename), but you can redirect `git diff` output somewhere and inspect that separately.

Comment: Great answer @torek! However, doesn't the `git diff` output that @Clament John added to the question suggest that the `if` statement **is** being touched in the `B`-to-`C` commit? I'm a bit unsure about how this could be happening if the `if` statement is only being introduced in the  `cherry-pick` commit... it should be a merge conflict at least.

Comment: @Timshel: we need to see the `git diff` output between the merge base and the `HEAD` commit. The original quoted text in the question doesn't match the added diff text either, which suggests there might be some sort of transcription issues. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870015/git-cherry-pick-failed-to-pick-the-right-changes/51870145?noredirect=1#comment90712453_51870015

Comment: @torek My apologies. I've updated the question to state that it was my mistake. Should I remove the question as it might be misleading?

Comment: @ClamentJohn: Well, it's up to you, but at this point the question has all the information in it to help someone else recover from a similar error...